# Php file_get_contents returning empty result

Tags: php, api, post, file-get-contents

I'm trying to receive posted (application/json) data to my Php project from using API.

My Php project file located there:

> v1/project/index.php

```
$request = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

When I use API url like this :

> [POST] localhost/v1/project/

It is working. But:

> [POST] localhost/v1/project

Not working.
I want to share this API without slash on end of URL. How can I fix it?

Comment: just use .htaccess redirection

Comment: That's a HTTP server config, with localhost/v1/project you try to post to file project whereas localhost/v1/project/ look for index in project directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all, It solved by .htaccess redirection (Google: non-slash to slash redirection) .

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```